# In sencha Ext.dataview.List itemTpl displaying every thing in one block

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

For the below code

```
Ext.define('ABC.view.ProductList',{
        extend : 'Ext.Panel',
        xtype : "productlist",
        itemId : 'Productlist',
        config : {
            layout : {
                type : 'fit'
            }
        },
        initialize : function() {
            var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
                '<tpl for="suggestions">',
                '<img src="{[this.image(values)]}">',
                '<h1>{name}</h1>',
                '<p>{description}</p>',
                '<span>{globalPrice}</span>',
                '</tpl>',{
                    image : function(value) {
                        var photoUrl = value.photoUrl;
                        var url = localStorage.httpPrefixAddress + photoUrl + '&token='+ localStorage.token;
                        return url;
                    }
                }
            );
            var productList = Ext.create("Ext.List", {
                itemId : 'Plist',
                emptyText : 'Empty',
                store : Ext.getStore('productStore'),
                itemTpl: tpl
            });
            this.add(productList);
        }
    });
```

I got output like this, i mean it displaying every thing as single list item.

[image]

Earlier for the different project i asked same question at sencha forum [link](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?245993-In-Ext.dataview.List..-in-item-tpl-displaying-every-thing-in-one-block)

This is the Json

```
 "suggestions":[
      {
         "buckets":[
            "Economy",
            "Expensive"
         ],
         "category":"Service",
         "charge":100,
         "class":"",
         "description":null,
         "gender":"Male",
         "globalPrice":9.2,
         "isPromotional":"N",
         "longScript":null,
         "name":"Universal-Adapter",
         "photoUrl":Photo?productId=9",
         "productId":9,
         "rank":31,
         "shortScript":null,
         "uom":"Nos"
      },
      {
         "buckets":[
            "Expensive"
         ],
         "category":"Electronic",
         "charge":100,
         "class":"",
         "description":null,
         "gender":"Male",
         "globalPrice":99.99,
         "isPromotional":"N",
         "longScript":"ajkl mnopabcdefghijklm nopabcdefghijk",
         "name":"Combination-Padlock",
         "photoUrl":Photo?productId=1",
         "productId":1,
         "rank":29,
         "shortScript":"abcdefghijklmnop",
         "uom":"Nos"
      },
      {
         "buckets":[
            "Expensive"
         ],
         "category":"Electronic",
         "charge":100,
         "class":"",
         "description":null,
         "gender":"Male",
         "globalPrice":99.99,
         "isPromotional":"N",
         "longScript":null,
         "name":"Luggage-Tags-PU-leat",
         "photoUrl":"Photo?productId=3",
         "productId":3,
         "rank":29,
         "shortScript":null,
         "uom":"Nos"
      },
      {
         "buckets":[
            "Expensive"
         ],
         "category":"Travel",
         "charge":100,
         "class":"",
         "description":null,
         "gender":"Male",
         "globalPrice":6.8,
         "isPromotional":"N",
         "longScript":null,
         "name":"Travel-Basic",
         "photoUrl":"Photo?productId=5",
         "productId":5,
         "rank":29,
         "shortScript":null,
         "uom":"Nos"
      },
      {
         "buckets":[
            "Expensive"
         ],
         "category":"Service",
         "charge":100,
         "class":"",
         "description":null,
         "gender":"Male",
         "globalPrice":15.2,
         "isPromotional":"N",
         "longScript":null,
         "name":"Travel-LED-Light",
         "photoUrl":"Photo?productId=10",
         "productId":10,
         "rank":29,
         "shortScript":null,
         "uom":"Nos"
      },
      {
         "buckets":[
            "Economy",
            "Expensive"
         ],
         "category":"Electronic",
         "charge":100,
         "class":"",
         "description":null,
         "gender":"Female",
         "globalPrice":40.9,
         "isPromotional":"N",
         "longScript":null,
         "name":"Inflatable-Pillow",
         "photoUrl":"Photo?productId=7",
         "productId":7,
         "rank":27,
         "shortScript":null,
         "uom":"Nos"
      },
      {
         "buckets":[
            "Economy",
            "Expensive"
         ],
         "category":"Service",
         "charge":100,
         "class":"",
         "description":null,
         "gender":"Female",
         "globalPrice":25,
         "isPromotional":"N",
         "longScript":null,
         "name":"Peg-Less-Washing-Lin",
         "photoUrl":"Photo?productId=8",
         "productId":8,
         "rank":27,
         "shortScript":null,
         "uom":"Nos"
      },
      {
         "buckets":[
            "Expensive"
         ],
         "category":"Travel",
         "charge":100,
         "class":"",
         "description":null,
         "gender":"Female",
         "globalPrice":99.99,
         "isPromotional":"N",
         "longScript":null,
         "name":"Dial-Lock-Strap",
         "photoUrl":"Photo?productId=4",
         "productId":4,
         "rank":25,
         "shortScript":null,
         "uom":"Nos"
      },
      {
         "buckets":[
            "Expensive"
         ],
         "category":"Electronic",
         "charge":100,
         "class":"",
         "description":null,
         "gender":"Female",
         "globalPrice":2.8,
         "isPromotional":"N",
         "longScript":null,
         "name":"Eye-Mask-and-Ear-Plu",
         "photoUrl":"Photo?productId=6",
         "productId":6,
         "rank":25,
         "shortScript":null,
         "uom":"Nos"
      },
      {
         "buckets":[
            "Expensive"
         ],
         "category":"Travel",
         "charge":100,
         "class":"",
         "description":null,
         "gender":"Female",
         "globalPrice":99.99,
         "isPromotional":"N",
         "longScript":null,
         "name":"Luggage-Tags-Plastic",
         "photoUrl":"Photo?productId=2",
         "productId":2,
         "rank":25,
         "shortScript":null,
         "uom":"Nos"
      }
   ]
```

@ThinkFloyd this is what i got, i tried as you said

[image]

as you can see, there is a line came for setting the hight

Comment: Can you share the json data you are putting in that store?

Comment: @Swar updated question with json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, as I saw, you have used a tpl which we generally use with `tpl` config for complete template rendering as a whole. For list/dataview, we do not specify complete tpl but only the template of an item. Hence we use `itemTpl` property. For your case, while you specify `itemTpl` with a `tpl` (which includes a for loop inside), it executes only once and iterates over all the suggestions and includes it in the first list item.

So, for your case, you should use `rootProperty` of your store which will set each suggestion as a model instance and List will automatically iterate over the store to give you the desired functionality.

**Store:**

```
Ext.define('ABC.store.productStore', {
  config : {
    ....
    rootProperty : 'suggestions'
  }
});
```

**itemTpl:**

```
var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
  '<img src="(photoUrl:this.image}">',
  '<h1>{name}</h1>',
  '<p>{description}</p>',
  '<span>{globalPrice}</span>', {
  image: function (photoUrl) {
    var url = localStorage.httpPrefixAddress + photoUrl + '&token=' + localStorage.token;
    return url;
  }
});
```

This should work fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I have observed that even though template html is small but the item background is big and pushes all other backgrounds down. Can you try wrapping your tpl in a div and give some height and border to see if template is rendering it properly?

```
var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<div class="my-item">'
        '<tpl for="suggestions">',
        '<img src="{[this.image(values)]}">',
        '<h1>{name}</h1>',
        '<p>{description}</p>',
        '<span>{globalPrice}</span>',
        '</tpl>',
    '</div>',{
        image : function(value) {
            var photoUrl = value.photoUrl;
            var url = localStorage.httpPrefixAddress + photoUrl + '&token='+ localStorage.token;
            return url;
        }
    }
);
```

and in CSS give some height & border to `.my-item`. Also check your list after removing image function or use `<div>` with background-image instead of `<img>`

Comment: Can you show me the CSS you have used or even better create a [fiddle](http://www.senchafiddle.com/) so that others can experiment with it